# Full width background, without a wrapper

Tags: css

I'm working on a site, and thought I'd see if there is a better way to achive the same result.

**The problem:** The page is made up of several sections, each one with its own background, that should be the full width of the browser. The content within each section is in a 960px centered. At present I am wrapping each section in a, seemingly unnessary, wrapper. Does anyone have a better soloution?

Example Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Problem Example</title>

<style>
    .content{
        width:960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 90px 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

    #header_wrapper{
        background: red
    }

    #content_wrapper{
        background: green
    }

    #footer_wrapper{
        background: yellow
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header_wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        Header Content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content_wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        Content Content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer_wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        Footer Content
    </div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Ideal Solution**: The same page but without the 3 extra wrapper divs.

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: I put the wrapper ids on the content divs and got rid of the outer divs, but then the colours got brighter. Do you have that 0.5 value for alpha so that they are dimmer?

Comment: The example in action for anyone to experiment: http://jsfiddle.net/R4ZDX/

Comment: Please don't write (a) tags in titles (b) greetings (c) thanks; cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are contradictory.

You specify that each of the three sections should span the entire width of the page (and contain different background) but the contents of each of these must be restricted to 960px. A single div can not simultaneously have 100% width and 960px width. Short of doing some JavaScript magic where you mess around with the spacing, you can not achieve this without folded divs.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought... I just didn't want the to be the guy using extra divs when they might not be needed.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to have dynamic height, and not to use an image for bg, i think it is the best practice

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Problem Example</title>

<style>
    .section{
        width:960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 90px 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

    .header  {background: red   }
    .content {background: green }
    .footer  {background: yellow}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header section">
    Header Content
</div>
<div class="content section">
    Content Content
</div>
<div class="footer section">
    Footer Content
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: that does remove the styled divs but he's looking for a solution where the header, content, and footer each have a background that expands to 100% width of the browser

Answer (score 0):

What you have already is pretty functional, perhaps the alternative is to remove the wrapper div for your `content` area and set it on the `body` instead. Minor savings but it is one less div.

Answer (score 0):

An approach that would work is to use pseudo elements (:before, :after) to add the background to the left and right of the containers that have a fixed width. This will work for simple backgrounds, but will probably become trickier quickly if you want more complex background with images.

To read more about this technique check out [this post](http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/) about it on csstricks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how relevant this question still is, but as I was just searching for this I found this question, and there might still be people interested in this other then me.

With a little tinkering around I actually got it to work, and I want to just present my solution.

```
<main>
    [your content here]
</main>
```

```css
main {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

main::before {
    background: blue;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -50vw;
    right: -50vw;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The same should work with an ::after element as well if needed.

Basically what I'm doing is creating a pseudo element of the same height as the parent (but you could make it bigger with negative values) and use a way oversized width, based on the viewports width. It isn't based on percentage since the percentage would relate to the `<main>` element. You could use a percentage if you need to support older browsers, but you would need to figure out a number for yourself. It's then put one layer behind the parent element to let it stay visible.

There is one slight drawback, that isn't actually relevant in my opinion though. With this approach the body (or whatever element is the parent of `<main>`/your element) gets a horizontal scrollbar since the pseudo-element is actually bigger then the viewport. You can easily supress this with an `overflow-x: hidden` on the body, and this shouldn't pose any problem on a centered layout anyway. I would assume that in a centered layout there should never be a point where you actually need the horizontal overflow.

I would assume this also works with floating social buttons if you were to use them (I didn't try that though since I'm not a fan of it), because they should be relative to the viewport, not to the actual size.

I don't know however how this solution works performance wise, since I don't know how render engines work these days. There was a time where everything that was offscreen was rendered as well (hence why the infamous element hiding technique found it's way into the trashcan real quick), but that shouldn't be an issue these days either way.