# DIV inside a DIV wrapper does not keep wrapper background

Tags: css, html, header, wrapper

I've been working on a website with a pretty standard layout, header, content, footer, each being a DIV with a 900px width inside of a page-wide DIV, just like the one described in this question:

[Full width background, without a wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201508/full-width-background-without-a-wrapper)

Now the problem itself is that whenever the browser window becomes less wide than the specified DIV width (900px) the background of the wrapper seems to disappear, showing the background color of the website itself. This also happens while using the code in the aforementioned question.

This is the CSS code:

```
#headerwrapper {
    height: 229px;
    background: url(imagenes/header.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat;}

#header {
    width:900px;
    height:229px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

And this one is the HTML code:

```
<div id="headerwrapper">
    <div id="header">
      Content goes here.
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `height: 229;` 299 what? miles? inches? pixels? watermelons per second?

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Here's a demo. I can't recreate. http://jsfiddle.net/pjykp/

Comment: @Diodeus Thanks for the remark, though that does not solve the problem.

@Blaise isherwood used the the exact code I have, just a different image. That being said, I used `min-width: 900px;` as suggested by an answer and that solved the problem.

@isherwood well it does happen, maybe I was not clear enough, but I already have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably can't see the background in the scrollarea. You need to set `min-width: 900px;` or `max-width: 900px;` so that the background will be shown in the scrollarea.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem, which makes me realize I didn't read enough about the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify width for the `#headerwrapper`, browser makes it 100% of parent container (div or body). So if width of view area is less than 900px - `#header` becomes wider than `#headerwrapper`, so background is not showed for overlapped part. You may add `overflow:auto;` to `#headerwrapper` so scrollbars will appear, but i do not think that is a solution. So it is better to add background for the `#header` or add `min-width` for `#headerwrapper`.
P.S. Specifying

```
  min-width:900px;
  width:auto !important;
```

for `#headerwrapper` should do the trick.

Comment: Well that's certainly a clear explanation, but the `min-width` suggestion was mentioned earlier on another answer. It did fix my problem, so I thank you too.